# How to query/report users with a specific managed package license?

Tags: soql, managed-package, reporting, licenses

### Background

We have implemented customer portal for one of our customer where they uses ServiceMax managed package, while creating user we assign ServiceMax licence to the user so that they can access ServiceMax objects. For the few user ServiceMax licence is getting disabled after some time without any intervention.

We have raised case to salesforce and ServiceMax support team, they were not able to trace how the ServiceMax licence is getting disabled.

Is there anyway how to find ServiceMax users those who are assined to ServiceMax licence in the organisation so that we can keep a count of the user to identify the missing  ServiceMax licence users

### Question

Is there a way to build a report or to query users that have this particular license assigned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a query in Developer Console, or via Workbench or Apex:

```
SELECT UserId, PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix FROM UserPackageLicense
```

If you wish, add a filter on `PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix` for the namespace(s) used by ServiceNow's managed package.

The object is not triggerable, however, so inspection is what you're left with.

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for the response.
Query is working but it is getting all the active and inactive users. I would like to query only active users. i have tried below query it is not working. Is there anyway we can query only active users.

SELECT Id,Userid,User.Isactive FROM UserPackageLicense

Thanks,
Anil Kumar

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's an implementation restriction on querying through the `User` relationship on this object. You'd have to do a semi-join `IN` or run two queries and combine them programmatically.

Comment: Hi David, Below code worked for me...String APP_NAMESPACE_PREFIX = 'SVMXC';

List<User> licensedUsers = [
   SELECT Name, isactive 
   FROM User 
   WHERE Id in (
       SELECT UserId 
       FROM UserPackageLicense 
       WHERE (PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix = :APP_NAMESPACE_PREFIX)
   )
];
integer count = 1;
System.debug('licensedUsers '+licensedUsers );

for(user u: licensedUsers ){
 
if(u.isactive= true){

count++;
System.debug('Number of users'+u.name);
 
}
}
System.debug('Number of Active users.....'+count);

Comment: I run this query in my org but return 0 results. Any idea why that would happen?